# Why won't \d in heroku show me the tables in my database?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

The tables that I created:

> ```
>  cryptic-waters-43339::DATABASE=> CREATE TABLE login (
>     cryptic-waters-43339::DATABASE(>    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
>     cryptic-waters-43339::DATABASE(>    hash varchar (100) NOT NULL,
>     cryptic-waters-43339::DATABASE(>    email text UNIQUE NOT NULL,
>     cryptic-waters-43339::DATABASE(> )
>
> cryptic-waters-43339::DATABASE-> CREATE TABLE users (
>     cryptic-waters-43339::DATABASE(>    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
>     cryptic-waters-43339::DATABASE(>    name VARCHAR(100),
>     cryptic-waters-43339::DATABASE(>    email text UNIQUE NOT NULL,
>     cryptic-waters-43339::DATABASE(>    entries BIGINT DEFAULT 0,
>     cryptic-waters-43339::DATABASE(>    joined TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
>     cryptic-waters-43339::DATABASE(> )\d
> ```

Did not find any relations.

Comment: It looks like you haven't finished your command. You should have put a `;` after your `)` in your `CREATE TABLE` command.

Comment: thanks a lot! this worked